# Inserting contents of one file into another file based on specific string

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to write a bash script that does the following:

1) Read the contents of one file (f1.txt)

2) For each line that starts with "<", but does not contain "start" or "item", insert the entire contents of a second file (f2.txt) in the line after. This change must be done in the original file, f1.txt

For example:

f1.txt:

```
<start>
  <name1>
    <item>
      stuff
    </item>
  </name1>
  <susan>
    <item>
      stuff
    </item>
  </susan>
</start>
```

f2.txt:

```
HELLO
WORLD
```

results, f1.txt:

```
<start>
  <name1>
    HELLO
    WORLD
    <item>
      stuff
    </item>
  </name1>
  <susan>
    HELLO
    WORLD
    <item>
      stuff
    </item>
  </susan>
</start>
```

How should I go about solving this? Should I read line-by-line, or even character-by-character?

Comment: hint: look for sed one liners.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this awk command:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {if (a) a=a ORS $0; else a=$0; next}
     /^ *<[^\/]/ && !/<(start|item)>/ {$0=$0 ORS a}1' f2.txt f1.txt
<start>
  <name1>
HELLO
WORLD
    <item>
      stuff
    </item>
  </name1>
  <susan>
HELLO
WORLD
    <item>
      stuff
    </item>
  </susan>
</start>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a pure bash script solution like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

readarray -t S < f1.txt
readarray -t R < f2.txt

for A in "${S[@]}"; do
    if [[ $A =~  ^([[:blank:]]*)\<([^/].*)\> ]] && [[ ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} != start && ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} != item ]]; then
        echo "$A"
        for A in ${R[@]}; do
            echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}  $A"
        done
    else
        echo "$A"
    fi
done
```

Runas `bash script.sh`. To modify `f1.txt`, modify the last line at the end of the `for` block to redirect output to it.

```
done > f1.txt
```

Output:

```
<start>
  <name1>
    HELLO
    WORLD
    <item>
      stuff
    </item>
  </name1>
  <susan>
    HELLO
    WORLD
    <item>
      stuff
    </item>
  </susan>
</start>
```

If the matches are in higher depths it would still make a uniform output as long as indentation is by 2 spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Just because you shouldn't use `sed`, here's how to do it using `sed`.

```
sed -e '/ *<[^/]/{/\(start\|item\)/!{r f2.txt'$'\n''}}' f1.txt
```

I'm sorry. You're welcome.